# Linq GroupBy Clause not including items with zero count

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a query below which is supposed to group the result by Id, EntityName, DocType, Jurisdiction. For each group the query also returns the ProductList items.

At the moment if the group contains one or more than one product, Then i can see the result giving out a group with a combination of Id,EntityName,DocType,Jurisdiction and ProductList, However if the result doesnt contain products for a particular group i do not see the group at all. What i would like to do is show the groups even if does not have any products in its group. So if the count of ProductList is zero, i would like to set 
      ProductList=  new List NettingAgreementProductDto. Any input would be highly appreciated.

```
          var result = from nae in nettingAgreementEntities.Result
                     join no in nettingOpinions.Result 
                          on nae.EntityId equals no.EntityId 
                     join np in nettingProducts.Result 
                          on no.ProductId equals np.Id
                     group np by new 
                               { nae.EntityId, 
                                 nae.EntityName, 
                                 nae.DocType,
                                 nae.Jurisdiction 
                               } into g                      
                     select new NettingAgreementEntityDto
                     {
                         Id = g.Key.EntityId,
                         EntityName = g.Key.EntityName,
                         DocType = g.Key.DocType,
                         Jurisdiction = g.Key.Jurisdiction,
                         ProductList =  g.Select(x => new                                            
                                        NettingAgreementProductDto
                                        {
                                           Id = x.Id,
                                           Name = x.Name
                                        }).ToList()
                     };
```

Comment: Isn't `nae.EntityId` unique in `nettingAgreementEntities.Result`? This sounds more like candidate for [Grouped Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join) rather than (inner) `Join` + `GroupBy`. Currently the [Inner Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join) is filtering your query,

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev Are you saying as long as i have nae.EntityId in the inner join i will never get the result i want?

Comment: No. I'm saying that your current query contains 2 inner joins, which will filter `nae` without `no` and `no` without `np`. While `GroupJoin` (or left outer join) won't do that.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev i mocked up a query based on your recommendation. if i post my query as an answer would you be able to correct it? it blows up when i try to do left outer join.

Comment: Sure.. But I would need the involved entity/dto classes. And  the definition of `nettingAgreementEntities.Result`, `nettingOpinions.Result` and `nettingProducts.Result` - are these `IQueryable`s from EF etc.

Comment: let me post my answer and i'll simply this for you

Answer (score 2):

To recap from the comments, currently your query is using [Inner Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join) for associating `NettingAgreementEntity` with `NettingAgreementProduct`s. This not only multiplies the result set (and thus requires you to use `GroupBy` after), but also filters out the `NettingAgreementEntity` without `NettingAgreementProduct`s.

You can achieve the goal by switching to [Group Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join) (or [Left Outer Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#left-outer-join) + `GroupBy`).

But why entering all these complications. EF navigation properties allow you to almost forget about manual joins, and also allow you to easily see the multiplicity, thus whether you need to group the result or not.

So what I would suggest is to add the currently missing collection navigation property to your `NettingAgreementEntity` class:

```
public class NettingAgreementEntity
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<NettingOpinion> Opinions { get; set; }
}
```

Optionally do the same for `NettingAgreementProduct` in case in the future you need something similar for products (it's a many-to-many relationship and should be able to be queried from both sides).

Also I would rename the `NettingOpinion` class navigation properties `NettingAgreementProductNavigation` and `NettingAgreementEntityNavigation` to something shorter, for instance `Product` and `Entity`. These names (as well as the names of the collection navigation properties) do not affect the database schema, but IMHO provide better readability.

Once you have that, you'll see that the desired LINQ query is a matter of simple `Select`s which convert entity class to DTO and let EF query translator produce the necessary joins for you:

```
var result = db.Set<NettingAgreementEntity>()
    .Selec(nae => new NettingAgreementEntityDto
    {
        Id = nae.EntityId,
        EntityName = nae.EntityName,
        DocType = nae.DocType,
        Jurisdiction = nae.Jurisdiction,
        ProductList = nae.Opinions
            .Select(no => new NettingAgreementProductDto
            {
                no.Product.Id,
                no.Product.Name,
            }).ToList(),
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated my answer (final query) based on your recommendation and now it is working.